# Biorthogonal system, Gram matrix, Riesz sequence in weighted Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable weighted Hilbert space, which means the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum=_{n=1}^{\infty}w_{n}x^{*}_{n}y_{n}$ for some sequence $w_{n}$, where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w_{n}=1$ and all $w_{n}$ are positive. Given a sequence of vectors $(b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which are linear independent and has a dense span. My ultimate goal is to show that $b_{n}$ is a Schauder basis.

In order to do this, I want to construct a family of projection operators $P_{n}$. The projection operator should have the form of $P_{n}x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\langle x,b'_{i}\rangle}{||b_{i}||^{2}} b_{i}$, where $b'_{i}$ satisfy $\langle b'_{i},b_{j}\rangle=0$ if $i\neq j$.

I figure out that if $b_{i}$ is Riesz sequence, and $b'_{i}$ can be obtained using the inverse of Gram matrix(see [here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.gatech.edu/dist/2/436/files/2017/07/12-notes-6250-f16.pdf)). I also find out criteria for $b_{i}$ being a Riesz sequence(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930155/example-of-a-basis-which-is-not-a-riesz-basis)). However those settings is in a standard Hilbert space. For a weighted Hilbert space, I think similar conditions can be worked out. But I cannot figure it out.

So, my questions are the follows:

1. How to find out $b'_{i}$?
2. What is the version of the Riesz sequence in weighted Hilbert space?
3. What is the condition of the Gram matrix being invertible in a weighted Hilbert space?

If someone can provide some references for these, I would appreciate it as well.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486016/is-every-linear-independent-set-which-has-dense-span-in-hilbert-space-a-schauder?rq=1